# How do I start up RStudio to point to a non-default version of R on Windows

Tags: r, rstudio

I have R 3.5 and 3.6 installed on my Windows machine. My RStudio by default points to 3.5. I want to start up RStudio to point to 3.6 for some sessions. How do I do that without messing with the global options, i.e. changing the default. I remember some website said that you press and hold some button before clicking on the RStudio icon. I don't remember what that button is.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that button. It is Ctrl on Windows. Press and hold on to it while clicking the icon. I pop up box will appear to list the options for you to select.